# Recursive Equation from Markov Structure

Tags: markov-chains, recursion, markov-process, recursive-algorithms

Suppose that:

- $z$ follows a discrete-time Markov process with a finite state space and transition-matrix $P$.
- $x$ follows $x'=g(x,z)$, where $x'$ denotes next-period $x$.
- $g(\cdot,z)$ is continuously differentiable and invertible, for every $z$.
- $y$ follows $y'=a(x,z)+b(x,z)y.$
- $z$ takes values in $\{z_1,\dots,z_n\}$, while $x$ and $y$ take values in the real line.

> I need to find a recursive formula for $\mathbb E[y\mid x,z]$.

As a first step, one could apply the conditional expectation to both sides of the recursive equation for $y$, which yields
$$\mathbb E[y'\mid x,z] =a(x,z)+b(x,z)\mathbb E[y\mid x,z]. $$
I am guessing that the Markov structure of this system should allow for some link between $\mathbb E[y'\mid x,z]$ and $\mathbb E[y'\mid x',z']$ which would then lead to a recursive formula, but I haven't been able to find it.

---

*Edit:*

It seems to me that the Markov structure implies that:
$$ \mathbb E[y'\mid x',z']=\sum_{z}P_{z,z'}\mathbb E[y'\mid g^{-1}(x',z),z].$$
I don't know how to formally derive this equation though, so I'm not sure it is correct.

Comment: It would be clearer to index the various random variables by time period, like $X_n$ or $X_t$ or something, so the relationship between "current" and "next" can be seen more precisely, and also to make it clearer exactly what is being conditioned on. This looks like some sort of filtering equation.

Comment: Variables with prime are "next period", variables without prime are "current period".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer with some progress. Let us use $x_t,z_t,y_t$ to denote the "current values," and $x_{t+1},z_{t+1},y_{t+1}$ to denote the "next" ones. Consider an intermediate conditional expectation with $z_t$ added:

\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}\left(y_{t+1}|x_{t+1},z_{t+1},z_t\right) = 
a\left(g^{-1}\left(x_{t+1},z_t\right),z_t\right) + 
b\left(g^{-1}\left(x_{t+1},z_t\right),z_t\right)\mathbb{E}\left(y_t|x_{t+1},z_{t+1},z_t\right)
\end{equation*}

Now, observe that $y_t$ depends on $z_{t-1},z_{t-2},...$. The Markov property works backward in time, so $z_{t+1}$ can be dropped from the condition, since $z_t$ is the "earliest" future value. Then,

$$\mathbb{E}\left(y_t|x_{t+1}=x',z_t\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(y_t|x_{t}=g^{-1}\left(x',z_t\right),z_t\right)$$

so if you already have a form for $\mathbb{E}\left(y_t|x_t,z_t\right)$, you can indeed use the above transformation, which is similar to what you have written.

The problem is that $z_t$ is not really given. You can write

$$\mathbb{E}\left(y_{t+1}|x_{t+1},z_{t+1}\right) = \sum_k \mathbb{E}\left(y_{t+1}|x_{t+1},z_{t+1},z_t=k\right)P\left(z_t=k|x_{t+1},z_{t+1}\right)$$

but the issue is that the backward transition probabilities are nonstationary, and it is not the case that $P\left(z_t =k|z_{t+1}=j\right) = P_{kj}$. These probabilities can be simplified if the chain is time-reversible or is initialized using its invariant distribution. The presence of $x_{t+1}$ in the condition also complicates matters.